# Node.js: choosing DigitalOcean city from location of user

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, geolocation, digital-ocean

I am using Node.js with my HTTP server. I want each connected user to connect to a real-time game server with WebSockets, and I want them to be connected to the nearest server to their location. I am using DigitalOcean, so here is the list of cities available:

- New York
- Amsterdam
- San Fransisco
- Singapore
- London
- Frankfurt
- Toronto

I need to use the location of the connected user's IP address and find the nearest city so I can connect to the nearest server.

I have thought up to methods to do this:

- Get a list of countries and divide them into region groups, each region pertaining to a different DigitalOcean city.
- Get the approximated longitude/latitude location of the user, and see the distance to each longitude/latitude location of each city, and pick the smallest distance.

Which of the two above methods is better? How would I go about doing the better one with Node.js and NPM? Is there another better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution to solve that is using **Anycast** or a similar solution: An Ip that redirect for multiples directions.

**More about Anycast**

Anycast is networking technique where the same IP prefix is advertised from multiple locations. The network then decides which location to route a user request to, based on routing protocol costs and possibly the 'health' of the advertising servers.

Depending on how anycast is implemented, it can also provide a level of high availability. If the advertisement of the anycast route is conditional on some sort of health check (e.g. a DNS query for a well known domain, in this example), then as soon as a server fails its route can be removed. Once the network reconverges, user requests will be seamlessly forwarded to the next closest instance of DNS, without the need for any manual intervention or reconfiguration.

**Links**

- [Anycast DNS- Part 1](http://ddiguru.com/blog/45/118)
- [Anycast DNS- Part 2](http://ddiguru.com/blog/45/119)

Comment: To be honest, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this :D. I'm just wondering how you could have the same IP for different locations, and why you suggested Anycast instead of Geocast.

Comment: I'm not sure how Anycast works, but let me have a guess at a system that I could use. I would have a master droplet which would redirect users to other droplets. The master droplet has a list of servers (droplets) which each have a value of online or offline, which is updated live via communication with those servers. I would then use [this tool](http://www.ipinfodb.com/) tool to find the lat/long location of connected users, and find the lowest distance to an online server. What do you think?

Comment: I am more than happy to upvote and accept this answer, but first I would appreciate some clarity... thanks! :).

Comment: If you just want something simple to check location and redirect the user for the nearest server you can make an API that receives the information of user with IPInfoDB (just like his country or latitude longitude) and there you can make some verifications an return an address to the user;


I talked about Anycast for you since it can make exactly what you want and more because it can handle load balancing and much more, but it is not something easy to implement.

Comment: Also there is the solution of [google play Real-time Multiplayer](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer#real-time_multiplayer_game_basics) the makes al the hard work for you.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Google Player Real-time Multiplayer does too much, and isn't what I'm looking for. I feel like I can't accept this answer, as I'm not exactly sure how to use Anycast and what will work best for me. You've given me enough information, and I think this is a good answer which will be helpful to people in the future. +1 :).